# How to take full page screenshot in chrome and safari browser using java selenium

Tags: selenium, screenshot

I want to take full page screenshot of webpage in chrome and safari browser using java `selenium`.

I tried:

```
File src1 = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
FileUtils.copyFile(src1, new File(path));
```

This code. But it is taking screenshot of only visible part.